# Using trigonometry to find intergrals

Tags: integration, trigonometry

[image]
While I am familiar with my rules of intergration this question strikes me as odd; I know that the integral of $$1/(a^2 - x^2) = (1/a)arctan(x/a)+c$$
My inital reaction would be to somehow tun that into *1/(4-x^2)* but I dont see anyway of doing that and the mark scheme says to start by letting **x=2sin(theta)** Which I dont understand at all, can someone walk me through this please?

Comment: Not that it matters here, really, but your formula with arctan is wrong to begin with; you need to have $1/(a^2+x^2)$ on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

substitute $x=2\sin { t } $ and change the bounderies $$\sqrt { 2 } =2\sin { t\quad \Rightarrow t=\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  } \\ 0=2\sin { t } \Rightarrow t=0$$ then finding $$x=2\sin { t } \\ dx=2\cos { tdt } $$ we get

> $$\\ \int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ \sqrt { 4-4\sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  }  } 2\cos { tdt } =4\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ \sqrt { 1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  }  } \cos { tdt } =4\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ t } dt } =$$
>   $$=4\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ \frac { 1+\cos { 2t }  }{ 2 } dt } =2\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }{ \left( 1+\cos { 2t }  \right) dt= } \\ ={ 2\left( t+\frac { \sin { 2t }  }{ 2 }  \right)  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }=2\left( \frac { \pi  }{ 4 } +\frac { \sin { \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }  }{ 2 } -0 \right) =\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +1$$

Comment: please elaborate on why you've changed the boundaries (or how rather)

Comment: because we substituted a new parameter $"t"$ and we should calculate all things for $t$

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-Put $\frac x2=\sin y$ so you have $\sqrt{4-x^2}=2\cos y$ and $dx=2\cos y\space dy$